Safely publish two npm packages at the same
I have two npm packages in one folder
project
|__package1
| |__package.json
|
|__package2
  |__package.json

I want to safely publish them both as separated packages. If the first publishing is successful and the second publishing fails - no one package should be published.
It should be something similar to how maven deploys projects with parent pom.
For example:
project
|__pom.xml # <- parent pom
|__module1
| |__pom.xml
|__module2
| |__pom.xml

If I'm in project directory and do mvn deploy I get module1 and module2 in Maven Central with the same version. And if something's wrong - no one module is published.
So I want to achieve the same with npm.

You can't do that, you'd have to immediately unpublish the first if the second failed to publish.

What reasons are you anticipating for failure? Could you use --dry-run as a first pass, then proceed with the real publish commands and unpublish either if something went wrong?
